# Is it true that all joins following a left join in a SQL query must also be left joins? Why or why not?

Tags: sql

I remember this rule of thumb from back in college that if you put a left join in a SQL query, then all subsequent joins in that query must also be left joins instead of inner joins, or else you'll get unexpected results. But I don't remember what those results are, so I'm wondering if maybe I'm misremembering something. Anyone able to back me up on this or refute it? Thanks! :)

For instance:

```
select * from customer
left join ledger on customer.id= ledger.customerid
inner join order on ledger.orderid = order.id -- this inner join might be bad mojo
```

Comment: You'd best tell us what RDBMS you are using as they are different on what they allow and don't allow. "Unexpected results" seems suspicious to me, but again it may very well depend (And almost definitely does) on the database.

Comment: I work primarily with SQL Server.

Comment: *"...or else you'll get unexpected results..."*: unless you know what you are doing and that gives the results you ***do*** expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that they *have to be*.  They *should be* (or perhaps a `full join` at the end).  It is a safer way to write queries and express logic.

Your query is:

```
select *
from customer c left join
     ledger l
     on c.id = l.customerid inner join
     order o 
     on l.orderid = o.id
```

The `left join` says "keep all customers, even if there is no matching record in `ledger`.  The second says, "I have to have a matching ledger record".  So, the `inner join` converts the first to an `inner join`.

Because you presumably want all customers, regardless of whether there is a match in the other two tables, you would use a `left join`:

```
select *
from customer c left join
     ledger l
     on c.id = l.customerid left join
     order o 
     on l.orderid = o.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You remember correctly some parts of it!

The thing is, when you chain join tables like this

```
select * from customer
left join ledger on customer.id= ledger.customerid
inner join order on ledger.orderid = order.id
```

The JOIN is executed sequentialy, so when `customer left join ledger` happens, you are making sure all joined keys from customer return (because it's a left join! and you placed customers to the left).

Next,

The results of the former JOIN are joined with `order` (using inner join), forcing the "the first join keys" to match (1 to 1) with the keys from `order` so you will end up only with records that were matched in `order` table as well

Bad mojo? it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.
If you want to guarantee all records from `customers` return, you should keep "left joining" to it.

You can, however, make this a little more intuitive to understand (not necessarily a better way of writing SQL!) by writing:

```
    SELECT * FROM 

    (
      (SELECT * from customer) c

    LEFT JOIN

     (SELECT * from ledger) l

    ON
       c.id= l.customerid
    ) c_and_l

    INNER JOIN (OR PERHAPS LEFT JOIN)

(SELECT * FROM order) as o

    ON c_and_l.orderid (better use c_and_l.id as you want to refer to customerid from customers table) = o.id
```

So now you understand that c_and_l is created first, and then joined to order (you can imagine it as 2 tables are joining again)